# How to get YouTube live streaming statistics

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to get YouTube live video statistics (like,view count etc) and save it on a file?

I went through the API, but still wondering which parameters I should use for this.

Answer (score 0):

A [stream's statistics info](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics) -- `likeCount`, `viewCount` -- is provided by the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint.

Query this endpoint with its request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) set to your stream's attached [broadcast ID](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#id). (Need not forget to pass a proper [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) request parameter too: one that contains the specifier `statistics`.)